# How to fix `Error: Unknown command: –prefix` in Mac. terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command, homebrew, prefix

The terminal shows the tip: "Error: Unknown command: –prefix" every time I open it .This problem appeared after I executed the “brew unlink / brew link”:

[image]